# sealed case classes in flow

Tags: javascript, scala, flowtype

I'm trying to emulate Scala's [sealed case classes](http://underscore.io/blog/posts/2015/06/02/everything-about-sealed.html) in Flow by using [disjoint unions](https://flowtype.org/docs/disjoint-unions.html):

```
type ADD_TODO = {
  type:'ADD_TODO',
  text:string,
  id:number
}

type TOGGLE_TODO = {type:'TOGGLE_TODO', id:number }

type TodoActionTy = ADD_TODO | TOGGLE_TODO


const todo = (todo:TodoTy, action:TodoActionTy) => {
  switch (action.type){
      case 'ADD_TODO' :
          return { id:action.id, text:action.text, completed: false};
      case 'TOGGGGLE_TODO': // this should give a type error 
        if (todo.id !== action.id) {return todo;}
          return {...todo, completed:!todo.completed};
  }
}
```

I should get a type error for `case 'TOGGGGLE_TODO':` but I don't.

Is there a way to fix that ?

EDIT:

I paste here the code from Gabriele's comment for future-proof-ness:

```
type TodoTy = {};

type ADD_TODO = { type: 'ADD_TODO', text: string, id: number };

type TOGGLE_TODO = { type: 'TOGGLE_TODO', id: number };

type TodoActionTy = ADD_TODO | TOGGLE_TODO;

export const todo = (todo: TodoTy, action: TodoActionTy) => {
  switch (action.type){
    case 'ADD_TODO': break;
    // Uncomment this line to make the match exaustive and make flow typecheck
    //case 'TOGGLE_TODO': break;
    default: (action: empty)
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make flow check exhaustiveness without this? This feels like putting the burden on the programmer …

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `empty` type can be used to verify that Flow is convinced of exhaustiveness

```
export const todo = (todo: TodoTy, action: TodoActionTy) => {
  switch (action.type){
    case 'ADD_TODO' :
      ...
    case 'TOGGGGLE_TODO':
      ...
    default :
      // only true if we handled all cases
      (action: empty)
      // (optional) handle return type
      throw 'unknown action'
  }
}
```

Comment: Really? I don't think so, 'coz `case 'TOGGGGLE_TODO':` still typechecks.

Comment: What you mean? I can see the following error when using `TOGGGGLE_TODO`: `(action: empty) object type. This type is incompatible with empty` (Flow v0.34)

Comment: Interesting ! Thanks ! I got confused for a second.

Comment: If I try your suggestion then I get:  `identifier empty
Could not resolve name`

Comment: @jhegedus which version of Flowtype are you using? The `empty` type was introduced in version 0.34

Comment: Here's a full example with flow 0.34 https://flowtype.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAKg9gEzjEUC8UDeBfA3AKH1EigEEARcgfRgHlzb0spiIAuKAcguroc4A0LCAA9gHAM7AATgEsAdgHMhshB3kBXALYAjCNKh5CrWLQDiZgDIBRGvUYZMLcOy50LNu-xVqom3fqGBEQusIhwpADGwLJw8ihMPF6MAD6mHrZ8tMGiYHDSwFCRcVIs4UwAFMDhHPBIKEIAhtGx8rXhUTFxKACU6AB8WPhQUBIA7rLAkQAWUBXNXfIAdKw9mMMjRY0S0NyUyZwcOtIQjQDWBJtQAPTXUACq8sVaWhDyhcDTshJQADYK0GqUC050B02gIKms1EjQ0UlkADdoI15AhgaCoAAzX5wMbOSAzCCRM4bEa3SLbXbuKyZeyHKDHU4XUlQBAQTGw37iOYLVocCBaMCgHobbD4bBAA

Comment: Nice ! Thanks ! I was using 0.33.0

Comment: You can simply use null instead of empty